# MVC 3 Razor @model vs. Model printing a property using @Model.pName vs. @Html.LabelFor(model => model.pName)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I have a question about the use of the strongly typed model in Razor views and printing their properties. In some cases I can use

```
@model Namespace.Class

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.property)
```

and it works fine, however in others that doesn't work but this usually does:

```
@Model.property
```

At a first glance I am not sure of the difference and why for example the @Html.LabelFor(model => model.property) will simply print out the property name in which case the @Model.property prints the value of the property.

I suspect this has a simple explanation, I just haven't found the right search terms so if you could either provide a brief explanation or a link that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Html.LabelFor` will *always* attempt to print the property name or the property's metadata value. This is so that you only really need to change the metadata in one place vs updating all your views that might rely on that property.

Imagine if you had 10 views all referencing `Namespace.Class.FirstName` and you just typed "First name" into all your views. Later you realize that you need to support other cultures and now need to change all references of "First name" to "Given name" instead. If you used `Html.LabelFor` everywhere then you only need to change your model.

```
namespace Namespace {
    class Class {
        [Display(Name="Given name")]
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Now you're done and everywhere that you referenced that property with `Html.LabelFor` will be updated without having to go through all your code. In addition it makes it easier to support different languages and so forth.